# Backward compatibility for dotnet assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

I've read the idea behind .NET Standard is no longer necessary in the new dotnet world. It is possible to reference an older dotnet assembly (e.g. targeted for net6.0) from a newer dotnet major version assembly (e.g. targeted for net8.0) and here's a simple example that compiles and runs.

Older assembly

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```cs
namespace NetSix;

public class Class1 {
    public static string Get() => "NetSix";
}
```

Newer assembly with reference to older assembly

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NetSix\NetSix.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {NetSix.Class1.Get()} from NetEight!");
```

Despite it being possible, I am looking for guidance on whether or not it is **safe** to do this, or if there are potential issues that might pop up (run time errors, security concerns, etc).

Comment: As far as security concerns, any vulnerabilities that exist in out of support .NET versions will remain.  Except when the parent assembly overloads/overrides it's dependency's implementations.  Hopefully that's obvious.

Comment: @McFlurry But the Net6.0 DLL runs using the runtime assemblies from Net8.0 in the example of above, so it's not totally obvious IMHO.